# sum values for most recent month

Tags: sql-server

I’m working with 2 tables, t_funds and t_psg2_nav.

In the t_funds table, the relevant columns are fundnum and br_cd
In t_psg2_nav, the relevant columns are calcdate, return_active_daily, and fundnum

Basically I need a query that sums the return_active_daily per fund for the most recent month. I think I need to use a JOIN clause, but that’s a little stetch for me right now. Here’s what I have…  the t_funds table i'm using is only for switching between fundnum and br_cd (a name)... its easier for me that way.

```
SELECT funds.br_cd AS 'Fund Ticker'
    , Month(nav.calcdate) AS 'Month'
    , SUM(nav.return_active_daily) AS 'MTD Tracking'


FROM dbo.t_psg2_nav AS nav
    , t_funds AS funds

INNER JOIN (SELECT fundnum
                    ,month(max(calcdate)) AS calcdate
            FROM    dbo.t_psg2_nav
            GROUP BY fundnum
           )  AS nav1 
ON nav.fundnum = nav1.fundnum
AND nav.calcdate = nav1.calcdate

WHERE funds.fundnum = nav.fundnum
AND funds.fund_type LIKE 'ETF'
```

Comment: You're probably using SQL-Server and not MySQL. Plase update your question with the correct info (tag). And which exact version you have, 2000, 2005, 2008, other?

Comment: shows how much i know - updated the tag, thank you. i'm not totally sure which version it is though... i'm guessing 2005

Answer (score 0):

Append this to the end of your SQL:

```
HAVING Month=Month(NOW())
```

or, equivalently;

```
HAVING Month=Month(SYSDATE())
```

*(edited)*

To show only records from f.ex. March (month #3):

```
HAVING Month=3
```

Comment: Replace `NOW()` with `SYSDATE()`, maybe. Using an old MySQL?

Comment: @user1001244 If it helped, please upvote my answer (and not my comment).

Comment: probably should have mentioned... i'm getting the errors "The multi-part identifier "nav.fundnum" and "nav.calcdate" could not be bound.

Comment: @user1001244 Well, that's a new question not relevant for the header / what you asked first. For answering that we'll probably need an overview of your table structures. Please ask that as a separate question, if needed.